# Sending HTML email replies using Webform in Drupal 7

Tags: webforms

How can I get Webform to send an HTML-formatted email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should download [Mimemail](http://drupal.org/project/mimemail) to do this.

Then, in the webform options, you can create your template with the field you want using `%value[machine_field_name]` to get just the value or `%email[machine_field_name]` to get the label and value.